# Create a global instance of an object within Android Studio App

Tags: java, android-studio

I am designing a Game in Android Studio. I have an activity with multiple fragments on it. I also have a Player object that I want to create an instance of.

```
Player player1 = new Player();
```

All these fragmenets on my activity will be making changes to `player1.`
Instead of passing this object to each Fragment and successive activity with:

```
intent.putExtra("Player",player1);
```

is there a way to access player1 from other fragments and activities without going through the trouble of passing it with the `putExtra()` method?

I tried making player1 static:

```
static Player player1 = new Player();
```

but, i couldnt access `player1` from other `.java` activity files.

So, basically, I want a strategy to make `player1` a GLOBAL object that I can reference whenever and wherever. I don't want to make all the methods within the Player class static, because I want to be able to have `player1`, `player2`, and `player3` files on my game, so I need to be able to create an instance of a `Player`, and I don't think it can be done if every method was static (right?)

I just started OOP, so I am sure there's something simple that I am overlooking, or perhaps rather than messing with modifiers there is a better way to achieve what I want. Maybe by using an interface? How would an interface work?

What about storing info in the Application Object by creating a class that `extends Application`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access it anywhere, and don't care about privacy, you need to make it `public`

```
public static Player player1 = new Player();
```

The default is package level access only.

You can access it by using this syntax in other classes:

```
Activity1.player1; // do something...
```

Note: There are likely better design alternatives that simply making a field `public` so you can access it anywhere, but that's the bare minimum needed. It's not recommended to do it in this way, and since you're learning, you might want to read up on some of these design concepts.

Usage of public getters/setters is usually one of the more common ways to access a field of a class/instance, for example.

```
private static Player player1 = new Player();

public static Player getPlayer1() { return player1; }
public static void setPlayer1(Player p) { player1 = p; }

// ...
```

> So, basically, I want a strategy to make player1 a GLOBAL object that I can reference whenever and wherever. I don't want to make all the methods within the Player class static, because I want to be able to have player1, player2, and player3 files on my game, so I need to be able to create an instance of a Player, and **I don't think it can be done if every method was static (right?)**

No, that's not true. Classes with `static` methods can be instantiated as long as there is a public constructor and/or it's not abstract. `static` just means it's accessed at the *class* level, and does not require an instance, though you can still access `static` methods from an object reference. `static` however also means that *all* instances share the same fields, so there is only one field, method, etc. across all instances of the class.

One design pattern you might consider using is the [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Singleton_pattern) pattern, which allows you to get a single instance of a class whenever you need it, so you don't need to mess with static properties and methods (which can have drawbacks if you don't need to use them).

> What about storing info in the Application Object by creating a class that `extends Application`?

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html), that is an acceptable means, though you might still want to think about some of the overall design choices and determine if that's really the route you want to take.

> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state. You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in your AndroidManifest.xml's  tag, which will cause that class to be instantiated for you when the process for your application/package is created.

Comment: **For testing purposes:** In Activity1, i have this line: `public static Player player1 = new Player();`. I also have a button that leads to Activity2. When the button is pressed, Activity2 comes up, and in the `onCreate` override method i have the line `player1.setName("mike")` where `setName(String name)` is a `public` method in the `Player` class. However, i get a "Cannot resolve" error on this line which means declaring `player1` as `public static` does not work - or i am missing something. @Ryan_J

Comment: @MikeJamesJohnson You cannot simply just use `player1` in any class and have it resolve, because that syntax defaults to method/class scope (only those fields declared in that class). You need to access it via the _class_ that defines it. `Activity1.player1.setName("mike");` rather...

Comment: @Ryan_J ahhh!! yes, i completely forgot about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone else was wondering, another solution is to take your class (`MyClass.java`) add `extends Application` and then go to your android manifest and add a `android:name` reference:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="companyname.projectname.MyClass">
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And then when you need to access your object call:

```
Player player = (Player)getApplication();
```

This will keep the object instance for the entire life of the app. It works, but i like the static method explained above. Also, i am not sure if this is a desirable approach...

Comment: Probably not the best approach, since a `Player` is not an application, but it's good to see its use in context.